# Install/Override Erlang Older Version R16B03

Tags: terminal, erlang, installation, version

How do I install an specific version of Erlang through terminal. I have "R14B03" now and want R16B03.

Comment: What platform? Have you looked for downloadable packages at [Erlang Solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp)?

Comment: The definitive source is [this page](http://www.erlang.org/download.html). Erlang is also available as a package on many Linux distributions. Refer to your package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you originally had R14B03 installed and you now need R16B03 you might benefit from an Erlang version management tool.

**There are a couple pieces of open source software that allow you to install and switch between Erlang versions:**

- **asdf** - Written in Bash. This is a generic version manager with support for Erlang, Elixir and several other languages. It provides simple commands for installing and activating different Erlang versions.

  - asdf: https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf
  - asdf-erlang: https://github.com/HashNuke/asdf-erlang
- **erln8** - Written in D, erln8 can manage Erlang, Elixir and rebar versions. I haven't used erln8 before but it seems very popular. https://github.com/erln8/erln8
- **evm** - Written in Bash, it is a complete version management solution. Relatively new. https://github.com/robisonsantos/evm
- **kerl** - Written in Bash, it's version management support is very basic. https://github.com/yrashk/kerl

Update:
Add evm